# How to create a mac script to automatically update at night

Tags: mac, terminal

I am managing a group of macs, and I need them to automatically update every night at 2 AM. What terminal command (or other means) should I use to make this happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about OS X system updates, the command is `softwareupdate` and must be run as root. Here are the CLI options.

```
$ softwareupdate -h
usage: softwareupdate <mode> [<args> ...]

** Catalog Management:
    --set-catalog <URL> Set the new catalog URL (requires privileges)
    --clear-catalog     Clear the catalog URL back to defaults (requires privileges)

** Manage Updates:
    -l | --list     List all appropriate update labels
    -d | --download     Download Only
    -i | --install      Install
        <label> ... specific updates
        -a | --all      All appropriate updates
        -r | --recommended  Only recommended updates

    --ignore <label> ...    Ignore specific updates
    --reset-ignored     Clear all ignored updates
    --schedule (on | off)   Set automatic checking

-v | --verbose  Enable verbose output
-h | --help Print this help
```

So assuming you want to install *any/all* available updates, you can use

```
sudo softwareupdate -ia
```

You can then use your systems management tool of choice to deploy a Launch Agent to run at 2AM.